# How to convert hint property to an observed item in ViewModel

Tags: android, mvvm

I am learning how to develop using MVVM. I created a small example, and I would like to observe the change(s) occured to hint property, so that every time the hint is changed the the corresponding callback in
VM "ViewModel" class should be called.

according to the code posted below, when i add binding to hint property, i receive the below posted error.

please let me know how to convert hint property into observable so i can observe any change occurred to the hint of the edittext.

**xml**

```
        android:id="@+id/actMain_LoginViewModel1_et_userId"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@{(chars)->LoginViewModel1.onHintChanged(chars)}"
        android:afterTextChanged="@{(editable)->LoginViewModel1.onAfterUserIdChanged(editable)}"
```

**error**

```
Found data binding errors.
****/ data binding error ****msg:Cannot find the proper callback class for android:hint. Tried java.lang.CharSequence but it has 4 abstract methods, should have 1 abstract methods.
file:C:\AndroidProjects\DesignPattern\MVVM_02\app\src\main\res\layout\act_main.xml
loc:22:28 - 22:72
****\ data binding error ****
```

Answer (score 0):

I think i found the answer to my question. setHint is neither an anonymous class nor interface unlike after TextChanged. Hence, the binding to it should be a callback that returns value. I modified the signature of the onHintChanged to be as appears below.

**answer**:

```
    public String onHintChanged() {
    Log.d(TAG, "onHintChanged chars: ");
    return "hint changed";
    }

    android:id="@+id/actMain_LoginViewModel1_et_userId"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@{LoginViewModel1.onHintChanged()}"

android:afterTextChanged="@{(editable)->LoginViewModel1.onAfterUserIdChanged(editable)}"
```